# NodeJS net.Socket: `connect` vs `ready` event

Tags: node.js, sockets, ipc, unix-socket

I had hard time debugging a problem with my NodeJS' code today.

I have problems when I open two connections to the same unix socket (reasons though); and for unknown reasons, sometimes it works fine throughout; and sometimes I don't get back any `data`, but `connect` is fired for only one of them.

I'm still trying to debug, but I deep dived into documentation and faced another question. As NodeJS Docs (12.x LTS) states: (about `net.Socket`)

```
# Event: 'connect'
Added in: v0.1.90
Emitted when a socket connection is successfully established. See net.createConnection().

# Event: 'ready'
Added in: v9.11.0
Emitted when a socket is ready to be used. Triggered immediately after 'connect'.
```

(https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/net.html)

I wondered if that is where I should look for error:

- what does `immediately` mean? Does it mean `synchronously`? If so, is there any difference between `ready` and `connect`?
- is there any point for one using `ready` instead of `connect` for doing `after-connection-established/opened` tasks?
- what is the difference between the two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This event is emitted from `net` for consistency across different APIs. See the original commit here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/1c8149417a5dec9b2af056f306822b8a22a09706

It was created to make developers' life easier when working with `fs` and `net` code, so that they don't have to remember all the intricate details of a given stream implementation.

In practice, the Node.js socket code does [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/5011009a593437d3e4ab157d448cc464c93c8cc5/lib/net.js#L1123):

```js
self.emit('connect');
self.emit('ready');
```

Comment: Thanks! Super nice for finding commit. Thanks.